# alternate different shas of the same file. why?

Tags: python, sha

can somebody give me a reason why i get alternate shas of the same file? but the same for every second sha?

```
>>> f = open('480p.m4v')    
>>> sha1 = str(hashlib.sha224(str(f)).hexdigest())
>>> sha1
'4aa8cf11b849b77f608302fdcdad3703dce54c33ba4bac80fa0ef700'
>>> f.close()
>>> f = open('480p.m4v')
>>> sha2 = str(hashlib.sha224(str(f)).hexdigest())
>>> f.close()
>>> sha2
'ae60e45200c960f79d25049ef0135709ca6edf246b3f9e53cd084e58'
>>> f = open('480p.m4v')
>>> sha3 = str(hashlib.sha224(str(f)).hexdigest())
>>> f.close()
>>> sha3
'4aa8cf11b849b77f608302fdcdad3703dce54c33ba4bac80fa0ef700'
>>> f = open('480p.m4v')
>>> sha4 = str(hashlib.sha224(str(f)).hexdigest())
>>> f.close()
>>> sha4
'ae60e45200c960f79d25049ef0135709ca6edf246b3f9e53cd084e58'
>>> f = open('480p.m4v')
>>> sha5 = str(hashlib.sha224(str(f)).hexdigest())
>>> f.close()
>>> sha5
'4aa8cf11b849b77f608302fdcdad3703dce54c33ba4bac80fa0ef700'
>>> f = open('480p.m4v')
>>> sha6 = str(hashlib.sha224(str(f)).hexdigest())
>>> f.close()
>>> sha6
'ae60e45200c960f79d25049ef0135709ca6edf246b3f9e53cd084e58'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason you're getting different hashes is because you're not really hashing the contents of the file, only the file object's string representation. For example:

```
>>> f = open('480p.m4v')
>>> print str(f)
<open file '480p.m4v', mode 'r' at 0x0224C9D0>
```

You'll note that the address of the object is obviously changing between the different instances, causing the hash to change. Apparently the memory location of one file object is reused by every second other instance created, causing the hashes to coincide.

To hash the contents of the file, you can use this:

```
>>> sha = str(hashlib.sha224(f.read()).hexdigest())    # read() slurps the whole file into a string
```

Answer (score 2):

`str(f)` doesn't give you the contents of the file, it will return something like:

```
"<open file '480p.m4v', mode 'r' at 0xb7855230>"
```

I'm not sure why this alternates, though.

Comment: Hmm well if `0xb7855230` is an address, maybe it varies if `str(f)` reads into a different address every time, so then `sha` would vary?

Comment: The `open` function evaluates, creating a new file.  It is stored in `f`.  If overwriting `f`, the thing `f` previously pointed to is destructed, freeing space at a particular memory location.  That location is the exact size required to open a file, so it is used by the next call to `open`.

Comment: +1 And as for why it alternates: Propably because of nasty internals of CPython's heap management. (Python 3 uses a different repr, excluding the id - giving the same str every time; very confusing...)

Answer (score 0):

As the others said, the reason this is failing is that you're hashing the object's string representation. I expect the reason it's alternating is because the string representation includes the memory address the file object is stored at. When you do:

```
f = open(...)
```

you store that file object in `f`, pointing to memory X. When you do the same thing again, `open()` is called and allocates more memory. Since `f` is still pointing to memory X, that memory remains in use, and the second `open()` allocates new memory at Y instead. However, as soon as `open()` returns the result is assigned to `f`. Now the file object pointing to memory X is dangling and is garbage-collected. The next call to `open()` will reuse the memory at X since it's free now (this isn't guaranteed, but is common)